# Is it safe to use an Electric Duster to clean PC?

Tags: cleaning

1. Is it generally safe to use an electric duster onto the PC?
2. Are there any components that should be exempted from being blown by
   an electric duster?
3. Is there a maximum air pressure (psi) that you should not exceed
   when using a duster to clean PC components?
4. Are there any precautions to be taken when using an electric duster
   to clean a PC?
5. For fans present inside the PC, do i need to keep them from spinning
   while the electric duster is blowing onto them?

This is because I wouldn't want the risk of liquids coming out of can of compressed air, and that pretty much I don't need to keep buying them. My order for an electric duster is already under way.

Comment: Im not sure an a duster is not more problematic in terms of esd then compressed air. Also, are you aware you can buy "filtera" that can capture much of the moisture from an air compressor? I bought one for a few dollars from my local automotive/tool/boys-toys store. (Ive not had opportunity to use it, but did use a raw air compressor on hardware a few times without oll effect)

Comment: Some of the blowers come with earthed mains, steel bodies & filtration… but they're not the cheapest.

Comment: Thats ok - I changed my old receptacles to accomodate grounding pins for modern plugs. That will add the capability for excess electrical charge to go through. 

As for the can of compressed air "filter", i think its just an extra hassle to find or to buy for use on a single can of compressed air. I find using an electrical duster makes much more economical sense. You also eliminate health hazards because cans of compressed air contain inhalants which can cause hypoxia when inhaled and are air pollutants to the environment contributing to the green house effect.

Comment: Looks like no one has ever used an electric duster to clean their pc yet :o

Comment: "to accommodate grounding pins" ?? Unless you actually have an earth (ground) wire connected back to physical/electrical earth, that is no improvement.

Comment: I do have a wire connected back to physical/electrical earth. I don't use cheat plugs "aka adapters" and I do prefer all my devices/appliances to have grounding pins if they do come so by default. FYI older receptacles only have 2 slots - 1 for the hot wire and 1 for the neutral wire.

Comment: OK. I come from a country where earthing is compulsory on all sockets & all plugs have 3 pins, even if they're double-insulated. I hear so many weird & scary stories of the US & other territories where basic electrical safety appears to be completely optional;)

Comment: hahaha yes thats especially true in older homes that never got their electrical wiring changed